# How to make a JFrame visible only if the control button is pressed twice

Tags: java, swing

I am creating an desktop application that runs at background and while clicking the control button it should be visible i have made the `setVisible(false)` to the JFrame  any idea how to do it . The application should triggered if you click the control button twice in desktop or in any application this should work.

Comment: Do you mean pressed the keyboard 'control' button? (Or, what's the control button?)

Comment: yes keyboard ctrl button

Comment: If your JFrame does not have focus, it will not respond to keyboard commands.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I think he's asking to have a way to register keyboard listener at the OS level. Google Desktop works that way, for example. To my knowledge, Java does not offer this API natively. Maybe some library does it but it's likely to be platform-dependent.

Comment: @Guillaume Polet: You're correct.  This is the month of May, where Java students world wide realize they're going to fail unless they get help.  I assumed I was dealing with another panicked student.

Comment: This is good case of where you need to analyze your requirements, determine the language that suits your needs, and use that language.  Unfortunately, I don't think Java is the right language for you.  It is potentially possible using Java Native Interface (JNI) and communicating with a C++/C# module that is listening to the OS Event Bus for key events, but I would only go through that trouble if you have to use Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done in your application.

If it runs in the background, it doesn't have the focus, so it can't react on that event. Any other application might have the focus and being interested in consuming the  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  button.

Think of multiple such programs, all in concurrence for that button. Which should get informed? Think of 3 Editors, all getting the next character typed.

Your OS or DE might have a way to define a hotkey, look whether your program is running (once?), and send a message to your application. The application might then react.